# Monero GUI connected to remote node takes long time to sync

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

I just formatted my Mac and reinstalled the Monero GUI and set it to connect to a remote node(node.moneroworld.com:18089), I had the exact same setup on the computer a day ago, and I don't remember the daemon synchronising, it used to just connect.

Now it shows me that it is synchronising and it does it very slowly too, and sometimes for short periods of time it changes to "connected" and then returns to "synchronising".

The logs("show status" in the settings) show this:

```
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Height: 60978/60978 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 3.89 MH/s, v1, up to date, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 7s

Height: 84278/1408368 (6.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 5.49 MH/s, v1, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 8m 25s
```

Answer (score 1):

You first described connecting to a remote node, and your description sounds correct enough.  But the output you provided indicates (a) that you're connecting through your loopback IP, meaning you're not using a remote node, and (b) the daemon is downloading the blockchain, which definitely may take a while (a few hours if you're extremely lucky, to a few days if you're unlucky).

Comment: I know, That's whats weird. It's downloading the blockchain even though I'm trying to connect to a remote node. but I don't think I'm doing anything wrong...

Comment: here's an image: https://imgur.com/a/xt97R

Comment: You may be able to solve your problem by clicking `Stop daemon` and then `Connect` (which will first stop the downloading of the blockchain, and then will use the remote node address you input).

Comment: Tried this, and then it changed to connected but didn't show my balance(it showed 0.00 instead of the real one), and it certainly it the same wallet.
Then I relaunched the GUI, did your suggestions again and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I would probably delete the wallet, restore from your seed (to ensure you did it correctly), choose a date/height around/before when the wallet was originally created (to prevent scanning the whole blockchain), and then connect to a remote node.  It'll scan only as much as it needs to, and you should be up and running.  Just give it time to sync up, which could take a while.

Comment: I already did that, but without specifying the block height, but I’ll try it now